# How to move a page 50px down, without having side effects

Tags: html

I'm developing some kind of website builder project, where I can put the page into a edit mode. Then the content moves 50px down and display the "edit bar". Well sounds easy BUT

- The background didn't move down ( fixed with background-position-y: 550px);
- Absolute Positions where wrong

That's why I'm getting afraid that just moving the site 50px down can break the whole layout. Can this really happen or am I just overreacting?

Might it be better to put the page into an iFrame, but then I have the problem with cross- frame comuniction...

BR

Comment: use absolute position for your edit bar

Comment: then it might overflow some other content

Comment: you mean overlap? and you can move whole content down on a condition that you've your markup perfect, using false positions or dirty markup will surely mess up your layout, especially in **IE**

Comment: can your share the code so that we have a clear picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure these will help, but just try to gather more ideas for you:

- you can use the method `Ken` mentioned.
- preserve the 50px space on top, and hide the editbar, when it is in edit mode, show the edit bar,
- place the edit bar on the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

How about putting the background and everything except the edit bar in a container div and then moving that div?

Comment: my there not be any other side effects. It looks to simple ;)